# Argument `user` is missing. Prisma relationship error

Tags: mysql, prisma

I have a relationship declared between the User and Login tables as follows.

```
model Login {
  id String @id @default(uuid())
  user   User    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId String @db.VarChar(255)
}

model User {
  id      String   @id @default(uuid())
  email String @unique @db.VarChar(255)
  logins Login[]
}
```

Then I check if the user exists in the database and if it does, I try to record the login history.

```
const getUser = await prisma.user.findUnique({
    where: {
        email: email
    }
})

if(getUser){
    try {
        await prisma.login.create({data:{
            userId: getUser.id,
        }})
    } catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof Prisma.PrismaClientKnownRequestError) {
            console.log("PRISMA ERROR", e.code)
        }
        throw e
    }
    
}
```

Despite doing everything according to the documentation, I get an error

```
Argument `user` is missing.
```

Still can't find a coherent answer on how to solve this problem. DB MYSQL

Comment: According to [the docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#connect:~:text=you%20can%20set%20the%20foreign%20key%20directly) it should work. Do you have the same issue if using the connect api - ``await prisma.login.create({ data: { user: { connect: { id: getUser.id } } } })``? It seems unlikely, but could it be caused by the different data type declarations - `id String` and `userId String @db.VarChar(255)`?

Comment: @user1191247 thx mate. Property connect is work for me

Answer (score -1):

When this error happened to me, I created an initial record in my table that linked the two to solve it.